# Notificação em mensagem, parecido com ALERT

Tags: javascript, html

Minha dúvida é:

Ao clicar no botão de enviar Se o campo nome estiver vazio, notificar em mensagem a frente do input: mensagem “Nome não informado. Digite o nome para ter acesso”,

```js
function validar() {
  var nome = form1.nome.value;
  var senha = form1.senha.value;

  if (nome == "") {
    alert ('Nome não informado. Digite o nome para ter acesso');
    form1.nome.focus();

    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Java validação</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Informe os dados de login </legend>
        <form name="form1" action="enviar.php" method="post">
            Nome:
            <input name="nome" type="text"><br /><br />

            Senha:
            <input name="senha" type="password"><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" onclick="return validar()">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Coloquei um alert, mas é a forma que estou sabendo.

Comment: Pq não coloca um `*` e fala que é obrigatório? Melhor do que perder tempo fazendo mensagem de erro. Pela boa UX evite que o usuário cometa o erro, e não foque em fazer uma mensagem falando que ele erro ;)

Comment: a exigência é uma mensagem mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Seria isso?

```js
function validar() {
  var nome = form1.nome.value;
  var senha = form1.senha.value;

  if (nome == "") {
    $('#balao').html("Nome não informado. Digite o nome para ter acesso <br><input type=button oneclick=$('#balao').hide() value=ok>");
    mostrarMenu('form1');
    return false;
  }
}
function getPosicaoElemento(elemID){
    var offsetTrail = document.getElementById(elemID);
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    var offsetTop = 0;
    while (offsetTrail) {
        offsetLeft += offsetTrail.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop += offsetTrail.offsetTop;
        offsetTrail = offsetTrail.offsetParent;
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1 &&
        typeof document.body.leftMargin != 'undefined') {
        offsetLeft += document.body.leftMargin;
        offsetTop += document.body.topMargin;
    }
    return {left:offsetLeft, top:offsetTop};
}

function mostrarMenu(atual){
    delay=setTimeout(function(){
    atual_menu = document.getElementById('balao');

        var X = getPosicaoElemento(atual.id).left + 35;
        var Y = getPosicaoElemento(atual.id).top + 35;
        
        $('#balao').css('display','none');
        
        atual_menu.style.top = Y.toString() + 'px';
        atual_menu.style.left = X.toString() + 'px';
        atual_menu.style.display = 'block';
        
        
    },300)
}

window.onload = function () {

    document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        esconde_menu();
    })
}

function esconde_menu(){
    $('#balao').css('display','none'); 
}
```

```css
#balao{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Java validação</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Informe os dados de login </legend>
        <form id=form1 name="form1" action="" method="post">
            Nome:
            <input name="nome" type="text"><br /><br />

            Senha:
            <input name="senha" type="password"><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" onclick="return validar()">
        </form>
    </fieldset>

    <div id=balao>oi</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adicionalmente as formas de validação por meio de *JavaScript* já postados, vou adicionar uma sugestão de validação direto pelo *HTML*

A forma padrão de exibir uma mensagem de erro no *HTML* são com os atributos `required` e `pattern`. O atributo `required` exige que o usuário digite alguma coisa no `input`, enquanto o atributo `pattern` exige que o usuário digite algo que corresponda a uma expressão regular.

Além disso. com o atributo `title` você pode descrever qual é a regra de validação do `pattern` para o usuário:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Java validação</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Informe os dados de login </legend>
        <form name="form1" action="enviar.php" method="post">
            Nome:
            <input name="nome" type="text" required><br /><br />

            Senha:
            <input name="senha" type="password" required pattern=".{6,}" title="6 caracteres ou mais"><br /><br />

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Aparentemente sim, Ronaldo. Obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa senão fui muito claro, é porque sou novo em javascript.